# creating android sqlite database with multiple tables

Tags: android

I trying to search for a helpful tutorials or examples to create a running application with sqlite database and has more than one table but I didn't found any..

Does any one know a helpful sites that provides a tutorials for sqlite database management with all operations on it?

Comment: Did you check also [vogella's SQLite tutorial?](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) or [Android SQLite Database Tutorial at androidhive?](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: thanks, I do trying these tutorials before but they also used one table only and my problem is that I can't handle more than one table and deal with them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android data storage guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) has a section about [DBs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). Though in its example only one table is crerated is fairly trivial to add more tables.

You should just do this in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE1_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE2_CREATE);
    ...
}
```

Comment: is this more efficient then doing db.execSQL(TABLE1_CREATE; TABLE2_CREATE;)?